# Displaying opencv cv::Mat format in a picturebox (when width is not multiple of 4)

Tags: opencv, c++-cli

I searched [Displaying webcam feed in cv::Mat format in a picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616529/displaying-webcam-feed-in-cvmat-format-in-a-picturebox/12628861#12628861) and wrote a simple c++ code for display 24bit RGB format in cv:Mat to a pictureBox such as:

```
void    ui_DrawPicture(PictureBox^ pbOut, cv::Mat matSrc)
{
    Graphics^   graphics = pbOut->CreateGraphics();
    IntPtr      ptr(matSrc.ptr());
    int         iStride  = matSrc.step;

    Bitmap^     bm  = gcnew Bitmap(matSrc.cols, matSrc.rows, iStride, Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, ptr);
    RectangleF  rect(0, 0, (float)(pbOut->Width), (float)(pbOut->Height));

    graphics->DrawImage(bm, rect);

    delete graphics;
}
```

Normally this works well, but when the matSrc.cols is not multiple of 4 (for example 1279), gcnew Bitmap failed 'cause iStride is not multiple of 4. I found the answer at [Bitmap Stride And 4 bytes Relation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735997/bitmap-stride-and-4-bytes-relation) and changed th code such as;

```
void    ui_DrawPicture(PictureBox^ pbOut, cv::Mat matSrc)
{
    Graphics^   graphics = pbOut->CreateGraphics();
    IntPtr      ptr(matSrc.ptr());
    int         iStride  = matSrc.step;

    iStride = (iStride + 3) / 4 * 4;

    Bitmap^     bm  = gcnew Bitmap(matSrc.cols, matSrc.rows, iStride, Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, ptr);
    RectangleF  rect(0, 0, (float)(pbOut->Width), (float)(pbOut->Height));

    graphics->DrawImage(bm, rect);

    delete graphics;
}
```

But this time, graphics->DrawImage(bm, rect) failed with System.AccessViolationExceptons.
How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: You will most likely need to make a copy of the input `Mat` and add appropriate row padding to its right side to satisfy the alignment requirements.

Comment: copyMakeBorder may be useful

Answer (score -1):

OK. I changed the code by Dan's suggestion, and this works well.
Thanks.

```
void    ui_DrawPicture(PictureBox^ pbOut, cv::Mat matSrc)
{
    cv::Mat     matDup( matSrc.rows, (matSrc.cols + 3) / 4 * 4,  CV_8UC3 );
    cv::Rect    rectSrc(0, 0, matSrc.cols, matSrc.rows);
    matSrc(rectSrc).copyTo( matDup(rectSrc) );


    Graphics^   graphics = pbOut->CreateGraphics();
    IntPtr      ptr(matDup.ptr());
    int         iStride  = matDup.step;

    Bitmap^     bm  = gcnew Bitmap(matDup.cols, matDup.rows, iStride, Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, ptr);
    RectangleF  rect(0, 0, (float)(pbOut->Width), (float)(pbOut->Height));

    graphics->DrawImage(bm, rect);

    delete graphics;
}
```