# Stride function in c#

Tags: c#

Can someone explain me how it's calculated row and column?

```
byte[] pixel = new byte[img.Stride * img.Height];
for (l=0; l< pixel.Length -4;l+=4 )
{
    row= l/img.Stride;
    column=(l% img.Stride)/4;
....
}
```

Comment: it is unclear to me what you are asking, but maybe this page on Image Stride will help you out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the link, [c# scan0 and stride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691955/c-sharp-scan0-and-stride)

[Stride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride.aspx):

> The stride is the width of a single row of pixels (a scan line),
>   rounded up to a four-byte boundary. If the stride is positive, the
>   bitmap is top-down. If the stride is negative, the bitmap is
>   bottom-up.

If you want to move from one row to the next, you need to add the stride to the address of the row you're currently looking at. Rows are aligned to 4 byte boundaries so that all kinds of code can access it more efficiently. (Various operations in CPUs are optimized to work on 4 byte or 8 byte boundaries.)

Thanks,
Christo