# Converting monochrome bitmap data into a little endian order hex string for Zebra printers

Tags: java, bitmap, hex, zebra-printers, zpl

I have a 1bpp monochrome bitmap image loaded into memory.  I have the image data loaded into a byte array.  I am trying to print to a Zebra printer and following their manual I feel I mostly have the code working except that when I convert the image data into hexcode and send the command to the printer, the bounding box appears to print the correct size, but the image is hopelessly scrambled.

I suspect that this is because the following method that I found on StackOverflow for converting a byte array into hex is reading each byte value in Big Endian order when I need it to look at it in Little Endian order.

```
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] b) {
    char hexDigit[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
            '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    for (int j=0; j<b.length; j++) {

        buf.append(hexDigit[b[j] & 0x0f]);
        buf.append(hexDigit[(b[j] >> 4) & 0x0f]);
    }
    return buf.toString().toUpperCase();
}
```

At this point I am stuck.  Does anybody have any suggestions how I can modify the above the code to read each byte value in the proper order for reading bitmap image data?

**EDIT:**

The image, it is James Bond mangled with a poor ad-hoc Floyd-Steinberg dithering implementation (thats a different problem altogether)...

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Well that didn't work, it looks like when I upload it then it gets converted to PNG.

**Bitmap data in Hex:**

> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 **01** FF FF FF 00 00 00 FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 FF FF FF 00 00 00 FF FF **FE** 00 00 ...

Hmmmm... I thought Monochrome 1bpp bitmaps only had two possible colors?  Why did image4j ConvertUtil.convert1 introduce other colors?  I wonder if this is the problem?

**EDIT 3:**

NVM, each bit determines the color in 1bpp, so each byte can represent up to 8 pixels.  This is likely correct.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the problem is nibble order. Are the images available?

Comment: @trashgod Just to be certain I dumped the bytes for the monochrome 1bpp data to disk to verify and sure enough it is well formatted

Comment: @trashgod I posted some more information and a hex output of the bitmap data.  I think your right, maybe the nibble order isn't the problem

Comment: Another factor to check is the [image stride](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2004602/230513); 31 bytes * 8 bits/byte = 248 bits in your example. Is that right?